# Android webview hangs/crash after continues running (2-3 days)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

I have created one Xamarin.forms application that runs URL in webview. The app is a digital signage player, So Android TV/Box will run forever.

I found that after 2-3 days the webview either became unstable/hang/crash. I have tried almost all the types of flags but none of them are working.

Some android TV/Box uses **com.google.android.webview** and some **com.android.webview**.

**Video Android box (Android 7.1  API 25):** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EU7Vf39wFxStNCGJPHyk519G4ifhSEUw/view?usp=sharing

**Log (Check Time stamp: 10-21 14:32:36.278 16584):** https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bt1vKYNo02Rm9GQA_Hw-PUV36vDvif3/view?usp=sharing

**Anyone have any solution?**

```
            MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient();
            MyWebChromeClient client2 = new MyWebChromeClient();

            webView.SetWebViewClient(client);
            webView.SetWebChromeClient(client2);

            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                webSettings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
                webSettings.SetSupportZoom(false);
                webSettings.DisplayZoomControls = false;
                if (Element.AspectRatio)
                    webView.SetInitialScale(100);
            }

            webSettings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
            webSettings.SaveFormData = false;
            webSettings.SavePassword = false;
            webSettings.AllowFileAccess = true;

            webSettings.CacheMode = CacheModes.Default;
            webSettings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
            webSettings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            webSettings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            webSettings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webSettings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webSettings.BlockNetworkImage = false;
            webSettings.BlockNetworkLoads = false;

            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webSettings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            webSettings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            webSettings.SetAppCachePath(this.Context.CacheDir.AbsolutePath);

            webSettings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webSettings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
            webSettings.MixedContentMode = MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow;
            webSettings.SetEnableSmoothTransition(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                //This flag is for the android box as those are rooted. It's the same displayed on the above video link.
                if (MainActivity.IsRootedDevice)
                    webView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
                else
                    webView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
            }
            else
            {
                // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
                webView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
            }
```

Comment: You could provide the crash log so that we can know the cause of the issue .

Comment: Log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bt1vKYNo02Rm9GQA_Hw-PUV36vDvif3/view?usp=sharing 

Check time stamp: 10-21 14:32:36.278 16584

Comment: This is caused by memory overflow . Each app will have a max memory , and the system  will clean the app which occupy a mass of memory . So it would be better to re-start the app with a fixed period(like once a day) .

Comment: Any other solution instead of restarting app?

Comment: Is their any solution that check continuously in service "Does my app is running right now? No: Start the app anyhow, Yes: Ok, all good.. no need to do anything"

Comment: You could send notification from client to service .